# Micromax MMX377G G USB Modem not working in UBuntu10.04 and 12.04 32bit

Tags: usb, usb-modem

Recently I bought a Micromax MMX377G 3G USB Modem cannot install in Ubuntu10.04 and 12.04 32bit 
Pls help me

Comment: Please gives more information. For instance, what happens when you plug it in any USB port : simply nothing or do you have an error message ? What manipulation(s) have you done to try to have it working ?